# Anyway to compile webkit with mingw?

Tags: windows, webkit, mingw, wxwidgets

I would build webkit for windows. But on [the webkit build page](http://www.webkit.org/building/tools.html) they say to use msvc compiler and I want to use mingw. I see that the qtWebKit can be builded with it, but I don't want qt.
Can I just compile with mingw instead of msvc without modification or I have to change some files ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build the fedora package of mingw32-webkitgtk and not depend on msvc or any other windows specific tool.